# Sudden FPS drop in multiple games

Tags: technical-issues, graphics-card

So, I've been getting pretty good framerate on most of the games on my new laptop. A couple days ago, I tried playing Minecraft modpacks which had some major problems. I tried to fix those, which resulted in, well, them not being fixed. Now, my FPS in most games is quite bad compared to what I was originally getting. Some examples are World of Tanks (used to get 60 fps, now struggling to get 30) and The Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth (had some minor framerate issues which are now more severe). My PC's basic specs are as follows:

> CPU: Quad-core Intel i7-6700HQ
>
> GPU: Nvidia Geforce 960M w/ 4GB of dedicated video memory + integrated Intel HD 530
>
> 16GB RAM
>
> OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home

I currently have the "Preferred graphics processor" set to "High performance Nvidia processor" in the Nvidia control panel, but that seems to have no effect.  Additionally, I have uninstalled and clean-reinstalled the latest drivers and reset both the global and Java settings in the control panel.

I ran MSI Afterburner during a battle in World of Tanks. What I saw was that I'm *not* using up all of my GPU's processing power (average: ~60%). Last time I checked, no power settings are limiting performance, so I have no idea what it could be.

Is there anything else I could possibly do to try and fix this issue?

EDIT: Lowered WoT graphics settings and saw no change in average framerate, as if it's almost locked at 30fps.

Comment: What did you do to fix minecraft?

Comment: I tried changing a few settings around in the Nvidia control panel.

Comment: "A few settings" matters. What were they?

Comment: The only ones I remember changing around are threaded optimization, vertical sync, and triple buffering.

Comment: However, I had only changed them for my Java executable, so I have no idea how that affected my other games.

Comment: Have you tried to reset those settings? Update your video card drivers? It sounds like you may have accidentally applied some global settings, not just minecraft. But without more info we don't really know.

Comment: Added more info

Comment: When you right click a game in Explorer or the desktop, and go to "Run with graphics processor", what does it say is set as the default processor? (note I don't think the option shows for Steam games, or if it is there at all on Windows 10)

Comment: It says that the default graphics processor  (at least for WoT, where I'm having the most issues) is the Nvidia processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this issue too with an i7 4790k and a GTX 970. However, not with the same games that you have included in your question.

But here are some solutions that have solved some users' problems:

1. Install EVGA Precision X and activate K-Boost on your GTX960.
2. Make sure you have every power setting (Windows, Nvidia) set to max and in every game.
3. Overclock your card and your CPU (Not recommended for laptops)
4. Unpark your CPU:
5. Reinstall the OS (doesn't work most of the time)
6. Exchange your hardware (this has worked for some people)
7. Download Nvidia GeForce Experience and Optimize compatible games
8. Check for overheating on your components using MSI Afterburner
9. Make sure your computer is set to the GTX 960 (mistakes do happen and sometimes the wire is connected to the wrong GPU output, but unlikely non-the-less. Usually not a problem for laptop users though.)
10. If you have something like an Alienware, MSI, or the new Razer Blade Stealth, you can also buy an external GPU to drive the display instead.

This problem doesn't usually have just one answer. However, I hope one of these solutions have worked for you. And sometimes, this problem is just different for different users. None of them worked for me in Cities-Skylines while it has worked for others playing the same game with a similar system.

And if you looked at a lot of other forums, you will see people getting mixed results (however, some peoples' computers do get better) so don't expect this answer to be 100% better performance guaranteed.

Comment: I don't think overclocking would be the safest idea for a laptop - remember that the OP *was* getting better performance previously. And as for exchanging hardware, it's a laptop, pretty sure CPU and GPU are attached directly to the motherboard...

Comment: Yeah I agree with you 100%. However, I was only listing all the possible solutions as some people do gain better performance when OCing. I will update the answer though :)

Comment: Funny thing is, the GPU isn't overheating at all, so I ruled out any sort of temperature issue.

Comment: I really really would NOT list overclocking as a possible solution for this. Its nice that you add a list of options, but its not needed to list the bad option that will not solve the problem; OP screwed up his settings (most likely) overclocking will not fix those settings. same for re installing OS, that is a very drastic way to "reset" something..

Comment: If it can solve this kind of problem, I would list it as a solution. Same for buying a new computer. It may be drastic, but that doesn't make it not a possibility. And I had this type of problem before where overclocking actually fixed it. It was in cities skylines and I was only getting 25FPS with a i7 4790k and a gtx 970. Overclocking somehow got it to be 60 stable. Re-installing the OS may work. But I have re-installed my OS several times to get a game working (didn't work). So I suppose it's opinion of what is drastic or not. But I appreciate the insight :)

Comment: I feel like reinstalling the OS *might* work, simply because I had to do a clean install of Win 10 (and thus reinstall the Nvidia drivers before I installed my games) when I first got my laptop, and I did get good performance after that.

Comment: so did you fix it?

Comment: Nope.. not yet at least.

Comment: Update: For whatever reason, reinstalling Windows worked. I can hit 70-80 fps with no problems at all :D